# Mediapipe Face Mesh landmarks visibility and presence attribute values are always 0

Tags: face-detection, mediapipe, facial-landmark-alignment

I'm working with mediapipe face mesh landmarks model. What I want is to find the 468 landmarks for a face and then filter out any faces with occluded landmarks. The model has these attributes defined as landmarks 'visibility' and 'presence'. But when I print out these values for all the landmarks they appear to be 0. For a frontal face they should atleast have a value greater than 0.5

Comment: The model has these attributes defined as landmarks 'visibility' and 'presence' ? Doesn't it only output 468 xyz coordiantes and just a confidence ?